# Longest repeating substring using for-loops and if-statements

Tags: python

I'm in an introductory level programming class that teaches python.  I was introduced to a longest repeating substring problem for a project and I can't seem to crack it.  I've looked on here for a solution, but I haven't learned suffix trees yet so I wouldn't be able to use them.  So far, I've gotten here:

```
msg = "kalhfdlakdhfklajdf" (anything)

for i in range(len(msg)):
    if msg[i] == msg[i + 1]:
        reps.append(msg[i])
```

What this does is scan my string, msg, and check to see if the counter matches the next character in sequence.  If the characters match, it appends msg[i] to the list "reps". My problem is that:
a) The function I created always appends one less than repetition amount, and 
b) my function program always crashes due to msg[i+1] going out of bounds once it reaches the last spot on the list.

In essence, I want my program to find repeats, append them to a list where the highest repeating character is counted and returned to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `len(msg)-1` as your range but your condition will omit one character with your condition, and for getting ride of that you can add another condition to your code that check the preceding characters too :

with you'r condition you'll have 8 `h` in `reps` till there is 9 in `msg`:

```
>>> msg = "kalhfdlakdhhhhhhhhhfklajdf"
>>> reps = []
>>> for i in range(len(msg)-1):
...     if msg[i] == msg[i + 1]:
...         reps.append(msg[i])
... 
>>> reps
['h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h']
```

And with another condition :

```
>>> reps=[]
>>> for i in range(len(msg)-1):
...     if msg[i] == msg[i + 1] or msg[i] == msg[i - 1]:
...         reps.append(msg[i])
... 
>>> reps
['h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `groupby` answer I alluded to on @Kasra's excellent response:

```
from itertools import groupby

msg = "kalhfdlakdhhhhhhhhhfklajdf"

maxcount = 0
for substring in groupby(msg):
    lett, count = substring[0], len(list(substring[1]))
    if count > maxlen: 
        maxcountlett = lett
        maxcount = count
result = [maxcountlett] * maxlen
```

But note that this only works for substrings of length 1. `msg = 'hahahaha'` should give `['ha', 'ha', 'ha', 'ha']` by my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

a) Think about what is happening when it makes the first match.

For example, given `abcdeeef` it sees that `msg[4]` matches `msg[5]`. It then goes and appends `msg[4]` to reps. Then `msg[5]` matches `msg[6]` and it appends `msg[5]` to `reps`. However, `msg[6]` does not match `msg[7]` so it does not append `msg[6]`. You are one short.

In order to fix this you need to append one extra for each string of matches. A good way to do this is to check if the character you're currently matching already exists in `reps`. If it does only append the current one. If it does not append it twice.

```
if msg[i] == msg[i+1]
    if msg[i] in reps
        reps.append(msg[i])
    else
        reps.append(msg[i])
        reps.append(msg[i])
```

b) You need to ensure that you do not exceed your boundaries. This can be accomplished by taking 1 off of your range.

`for i in (range(len(msg)-1))`

Comment: You are correct. Misplaced bracket. Updated, thank you for catching that.